# Ansible - How to test every item in list with until when list is an unknown length

Tags: ansible

I am using the `dig` command in an ansible.builtin.command and storing the results to the variable `result`. One of my `until` tests is `result.stdout_lines|length >= 3` as we are waiting `until` as least 3 results are available. I also want to ensure that every line is an IPv4 address but the list length is unknown. Sometimes it will be 3 lines and sometimes it will be more.

I am trying to figure out how I can perform an `until` test on every item in a list when we don't know how long the list is.

Here's the task so far:

```yaml
- name: Get database hosts  # noqa no-changed-when
  ansible.builtin.command: dig @127.0.0.1 -p 8600 +short db-addr.service.consul
  register: result
  until: result.stdout_lines|length >= 3
  delay: 15
  retries: 40
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test if [all](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-if-a-list-value-is-true) items are [valid IP addresses](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#ip-address-filters)

```yaml
    - name: Get database hosts  # noqa no-changed-when
      ansible.builtin.command: dig @127.0.0.1 -p 8600 +short db-addr.service.consul
      register: result
      until:
        - result.stdout_lines|length >= 3
        - result.stdout_lines|map('ansible.netcommon.ipaddr')|list is all
      delay: 15
      retries: 40
```

---

Q: ***"Output only items in the list that are IPv4."***

A: You can postpone the testing of the validity, e.g.

```yaml
    - ansible.builtin.command: printf '127.0.0.1\n127.0.0.2\n127.0.0.X\n'
      register: result
      until: result.stdout_lines|length >= 3
      delay: 15
      retries: 40
```

The result will be

```yaml
result.stdout_lines:
  - 127.0.0.1
  - 127.0.0.2
  - 127.0.0.X
```

Testing the validity gives

```yaml
result.stdout_lines|map('ansible.netcommon.ipaddr')|list:
  - 127.0.0.1
  - 127.0.0.2
  - false
```

Now, joining the items will include also `false` item(s)

```yaml
result.stdout_lines|map('ansible.netcommon.ipaddr')|join(','): 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2,False
```

Instead, you might want to very efficiently *select* valid items only

```yaml
result.stdout_lines|map('ansible.netcommon.ipaddr')|select():
  - 127.0.0.1
  - 127.0.0.2
```

Comment: That's a goof answer too. I think my answer is more efficient but your response does proivide a way to test each item in the list, which was my question, so I am going to mark this as the right answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
  ansible.builtin.command: dig @127.0.0.1 -p 8600 +short db-addr.service.consul
  register: db_hosts
  until: db_hosts.stdout_lines | ansible.netcommon.ipv4 | length >= 3
  delay: 15
  retries: 40
```

This will output only items in the list that are IPv4 and then I can check the length of that data. I can then use `{{ db_hosts.stdout_lines | ansible.netcommon.ipv4 | join(',') }}` in a template to only use the IPv4 output so, I'm not testing each item but I am only extracting items that meet my criteria.

Comment: Instead of joining, you might want to [select](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.select) valid addresses only.